# verifybamid results with freemix < 2% and chipmix > 10%

Tags: sam, snp

I ran verifyBAMID on each 200 chip-seq BAM files with input merged vcf file of Genotypes of 600 samples ( 200 of them are chip-seq individuals). I had AF,AC,AN in the info column which was calculated using these genotypes.

~80% of 200 samples are Caucasians.

I am struggling to decide for the samples which have freemix < 2% but chipmix >2%.

For sample 1365, I had histone modified chip-seq sample 1365_A with two input samples 1365_Pos_IN_2, 1365_Pos_IN_1.

1. histone modified chip-seq BAM 1365_A has .00669  whereas chipmix is 0.3765 where with input samples it does resonable job with correct matching of genotype column and reasonable chipmix and freemix values.

   Why is chipmix so high for histone sample?

   ```
   SEQ_ID  RG  CHIP_ID #SNPS   #READS  AVG_DP  FREEMIX FREELK1 FREELK0 FREE_RH FREE_RA CHIPMIX CHIPLK1 CHIPLK0 CHIP_RH CHIP_RA DPREF   RDPHET  RDPALT
   1365_A  ALL 1365_A  683278  436495  0.64    **0.00669** 160631.69   160867.97   NA  NA  **0.37645** 145839.46   194576.92   NA  NA  0.657   0.9478  0.9369
   1365_Pos_IN_2   ALL 1365_A  683278  1770725 2.59    **0.00320** 676736.66   676773.49   NA  NA  **0.00298** 425582.72   426459.54   NA  NA  2.598   0.9965  0.9923
   1365_Pos_IN_1   ALL 1365_A  683278  1127574 1.65    **0.00000** 446421.43   446421.43   NA  NA  **0.00193** 254020.46   254353.15   NA  NA  1.653   0.9961  0.9982
   ```
2. What does it mean when your target sample matched with the intended sample genotype from a vcf file with < 2% free mix value, but with chipmix value > 2%?

   for sample 1368_A and 1213_A

   ```
   1368_A  ALL 1368_A  683278  450800  0.66    **0.01019** 167252.18   167673.56   NA  NA  **0.56004** 158591.79   248605.77   NA  NA  0.677   0.9507  0.9477
   1213_A  ALL 1213_A  683278  945562  1.38    **0.01361** 345881.30   347208.39   NA  NA  **0.97533** 346470.85   647079.17   NA  NA  1.396   0.9783  0.9891
   ```
3. This is clearly contaminated sample with 1287_A. then why is its chipmix not 0.9?

   ```
   1215_Pos_IN ALL 1287_A  683278  3336277 4.88    **0.15412** 1360018.71  1407231.58  NA  NA  **0.18590** 1109098.83  1431053.16  NA  NA  4.900   0.9941  0.9917
   ```